Is scalar index (e.g. Inverted Index) loaded in memory?
How should we accurately account for scalar indexes when calculating the memory requirements of query nodes? Could we also include additional documentation on this topic? Thanks!

Scalar index is loaded into memory.
The document already shows how to estimate scalar index size: https://milvus.io/docs/scalar_index.md

Short answer: Yes?
it can be specifically implemented to purposefully load to memory, but it depends on the specific implementation and use case. In some systems, the entire inverted index is loaded into memory to ensure fast search and retrieval times.
This is not useful for large data structures though.
Hope this helped.

I have reviewed the comment below and YES is the answer.
